# Props Function Error in my React Application

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So my code structure is this:

1. I have a parent component named **PO Form**. This component renders a child component named Input Table.

```
export const POForm = (props) => {

return(
   <InputTable />
)
}
```

2. In the **Input Table** component, I have a table.  This table contains a set of inputs where I can type some data.

```
export const InputTable = (props) => {
 const [rows, setRows] = useState([{ key: 0, index: 0 }]);
 const handleAddRow = (newRowData) => {
    const newRow = {
      key: rows.length,
      index: rows.length,
      articleData: newRowData,
    };
    setRows([...rows, newRow]);
  };
 return(
  <table>
     <thead>....</thead>
     <tbody>
        {rows.map((row, index) => (
              <TableRow
                key={row.key}
                index={index}
                rowData={row}
                onChangeArticle={(newValue) =>
                  handleRowArticleChange(index, newValue)
                }
                onDelete={handleDeleteRow}
                openArticleDropdown={props.openArticleDropdown}
                setOpenArticleDropdown={props.setOpenArticleDropdown}
              />
            ))}
     </tbody>
  </table>
  <button className="ml-2 border-2 rounded px-4" onClick={handleAddRow}>
            Add Line
  </button>

  <ArticleModal
        showArticleModal={props.showArticleModal}
        setShowArticleModal={props.setShowArticleModal}
        handleAddRow={handleAddRow}
      />

  )

}
```

As you can see, my table body contains another component for my table row. The idea is that I can add a new table row when I click the Add Line button to fill another set of data.

Also, my Input Table component above contains an Article Modal component. This article modal component pops a modal in the screen where I can type a new article. After submitting, the data should display in the input field in my table.

My **current problem** is that when I click submit on the Article Modal component, I am receiving this error: **Uncaught TypeError: props.handleAddRow is not a function**. I tried reviewing my code but I can't figure out why is it not working. The prop passed has the correct name.

3. This is my Article Modal component:

```
export const ArticleModal = (props) => {
  const [newArticle, setNewArticle] = useState("");
  
  const addNewArticle = () => {
    **props.handleAddRow(newArticle);**
    setNewArticle("");
    props.setShowArticleModal(false);
  };
}

return(
 <input
              type="text"
              className="border-2 w-4/5"
              value={newArticle}
              onChange={handleArticleInputChange}
              required
            />

<button
              className="border-2 mt-5 px-3 rounded bg-blue-300"
              onClick={addNewArticle}
            >
              Save
            </button>

)
```

As can be gleaned above, I the passed props is added to my addNewArticle function. But whenever I click on the Save button, it gives me that error.

4. This is my **TableRow** component:

```
export const TableRow = ({
  index,
  rowData,
  onDelete,
  openArticleDropdown,
  setOpenArticleDropdown,
  onChangeArticle,
}) => {
 
  return (
    <>
      <tr className="hover:bg-gray-100 hover:shadow-sm">
        <td className="p-2 border resize-horizontal overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap ">
          {index + 1}
        </td>
        <td className="p-2 border resize-horizontal overflow-hidden whitespace-nowrap relative">
          <input
            className="border-2 h-8 w-full pr-10 pl-3 cursor-pointer"
            value={rowData.articleData}
            onChange={(e) => onChangeArticle(e.target.value)}
            onFocus={() => setOpenArticleDropdown(!openArticleDropdown)}
          />
          <i>
            <IoIcons.IoMdArrowDropdown
              className="absolute right-3 top-3 text-2xl cursor-pointer"
              onClick={() => setOpenArticleDropdown(!openArticleDropdown)}
            />
          </i>
        </td>
       </tr>

   <>

}
```

**This is a photo of the table row:**
[image]

When I click on the **Article Dropwdown**:
[image]

**The Article Modal:**
[image]

Now when I type a new item then click save, the error is: **Uncaught TypeError: props.handleAddRow is not a function** and I don't know why!

The whole idea is when I click save, the data should display on the input field of the article then be added to the dropdown. Then, when I click on "Add Line", a new table row appears:

[image]

Then, a new item will be added repeating the same step. Then the data from the modal should be displayed on the second article input. But as you can see, an [object object] can be seen on the new line.

Sorry it's a bit long but, I really want to solve these issues. Thank you to whoever can solve this. :)

I reviewed my code over and over to check if I am passing the correct props, -- spelling. But the passed props is correct. I also tried console.log(props) inside my ArticleModal component to check all the props passed and the handleAddRow is not in the log. So something is definitely not right since the prop itself is not appearing.

Comment: I‘m assuming the problem comes from the passed argument inside handleAddRow function, which is newArticle. 
In your onclick event try to pass that function instead of addNewArticle and check newArticle if it exists only then pass as an argument of handleAddRow function. Try it and if doesn’t work add your code in codesandbox and post the link so that we can debug easier.

Comment: Hi! I tried your suggestion but didn't work. I made a bunch of different approach and that original error went away. I am however currently facing a major blocker.

The issue is still focused on the Article Input. The intention is, to click on the Article input dropdown, Add new item in the modal, when saved, data should display on the article input on each table row. But, it doesn't display. 

Please see my code sandbox link below:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-sun-8m7ptq?file=/src/pages/InputTable.jsx:3774-4003

Disregard the lacking design.

Comment: My codesandbox Link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-sun-8m7ptq?file=/src/pages/InputTable.jsx:3774-4003

The goal is to have separate data for each table row.

The modal is used only for adding data to the article input and display that data.

Then, another table row will be added and will contain new set of data.

I have no idea how to solve this yet. A new fresh of eyes is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass function with the parameters as props in react.

Pass just the function and test it again.

```
     <ArticleModal
        ...
        onChangeArticle={handleRowArticleChange}
        ...
      />
```

Another issue was that, when you create a new table row, you initilize `article` input as a `newRowData` . But newRowData can be also empty or undefined, so you should also consider that case as well.

```
const handleAddRow = (newRowData) => {
    const newRow = {
      ...
      article: newRowData.length > 0 ? newRowData : "",
      ...
    };
    setTableRowData([...tableRowData, newRow]);
  };
```

Here is the updated [sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-kapitsa-njtqgr?file=/src/pages/InputTable.jsx:628-1044)

Comment: Wow, that worked Sir! Thanks! However, another issue rose. While I can add an item from the article modal and render that in the input table, it seems that I cannot type  anything on the article input element in the table row. When I try to, the index automatically displays. And also, I tried adding another line and test adding another item from the modal, sometimes it renders, sometimes its not.

Comment: Check sandbox link, it's fixed now https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-kapitsa-njtqgr?file=/src/pages/InputTable.jsx

Comment: Sure thing! Do you mean the up arrow beside your original comment? I'm having a pop up message that says I need 15 reputation to cast a vote. Or is there any button? Sorry I'm not that familiar with the buttons here I'm still on my journey as a self-taught. But, nearing to apply for jobs after I finish this personal project. (crossing my fingers)

Comment: Sir, I really need your help on this one. I figured out rendering the input values when I add and submit from the modal. No longer have problem on that. What I'm trying to achieve now is that when I add a new line, that line will be independent of the other input groups. Although they can share the state for the added items, I the searchQuery, selectedValue should be a separate state for each element. Not sure if I can explain it well just see this codesandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/s/article-code-887w2t

Focus on the Input Table and Table Row components.

Comment: I clicked on the check mark. Does that work for you?

Comment: @JapYG consider please to post a new question for that particular question. 
Tag me there, I’ll be happy to answer there

Comment: I would love to Sir but currently, I can't post another question as someone closed one of my previous questions and finds it somewhat lacking. So StackOverflow is not letting me post another question until after 3 days, lol. If you're comfortable, do you have Discord or somewhere we can connect? Otherwise, I'll just wait until I am allowed to post another question and would certainly tag you there. :)

Comment: Ok, I’ll take a look later